# "No frameworks were found" when trying to run .NET Core app

Tags: .net, .net-core

On the PC where I can run the app itself, but when I try to `dotnet publish` and then run the resulting exe file, this happens:

```
App: C:\code\dimensionx\build\portalreact\PortalReact.exe
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\code\dimensionx\build\portalreact\
```

> No frameworks were found.

Here are the installed runtimes:

```
PS C:\code\dimensionx\build\portalreact> dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

What on earth could be missing?

Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a solution?
I see that the .NET location is pointing to the project folder and not the shared runtime folder.

Comment: I think that I just gave up on publish and am using dotnet build now.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I resolved the issue by this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77498237/framework-dependent-net8-app-no-frameworks-were-found