# Framework dependent .NET8 app: No frameworks were found

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

After upgrading our application from .NET7 to .NET8 I get the following error when trying to run the published application: You must install or update .NET to run this application.

The application is published as framework dependent win-x64.
I installed .NET8 runtime & SDKS.

If you take a look at the `.NET location` it tries to look for .NET in a path local to my application and not in `C:\Program Files\dotnet`

Does anyone know what changed here from .NET 7 to 8 or how to fix this?

```
F:\myapp>MyApp.exe

You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: F:\myapp\MyApp.exe
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: F:\myapp\

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=8.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

dotnet --list-runtimes

```
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

Comment: can you create a new .net 8 project and see if it works? if yes, I want to see your csproj file.

Comment: I think this link is relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/deployment/7.0/multilevel-lookup. I assume in OP's case there is an installation in F:\myapp that is first encountered. I solved my similar issue by installing the sdk in the "/usr/lib/dotnet" folder. Which was the folder that was reported as ".NET location" in my version of the error above. In the sdk subfolder of that location there was no .net8.

Answer (score 7):

Check if you have a remnant hostfxr.dll file in your target deployment directory by any chance - that caused the same problem for us.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/8982

Answer (score 0):

Setting the environment variable DOTNET_ROOT to C:\Program Files\dotnet should solve that the .NET location is wrong. You can do this (temporary) with Powershell like this:

```
$Env:DOTNET_ROOT="C:\Program Files\dotnet"
```

More info: [.NET Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables#dotnet_root-dotnet_rootx86)